# Django + Daphne hot reload after code updates

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework, daphne

I am running a Django restserver application served by Daphne and Nginx acting as reverse proxy. I also have a periodic cron job that pulls updated code from my git to the server.

I am not able to find a way to do a hot reload and regenerate the pyc files like it how it does in Django development server. Is there a good way to go about this?

Don't want to restart my entire server for this.

Answer (score 2):

This is not supported yet. There is an open issue here:
https://github.com/django/daphne/issues/9

Comment: yeah, true and reading the github issue it will never be supported. But uvicorn and hypercorn do :'-)

Answer (score 1):

In the docker container, by ending the process and then restarting

```sh
$ ps ax
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
    1 ?        Ssl    0:01 /usr/local/bin/python /usr/local/bin/daphne -b 0.0.0.0 -p 8000 proj.asgi:application
    8 pts/0    Ss     0:00 /bin/sh
   19 pts/0    S      0:00 bash
   20 pts/0    R+     0:00 ps ax

$ kill 9 1
```